# Why does my code snippet (intended to prevent receiving the same result twice consecutively) not do anything?

Tags: java

```
    while(true){
        while(word.equals(lastWord)){ 
            word = wordList[genNum.nextInt(15)];
        }
        System.out.println(word);
        word = lastWord;
        word = wordList[genNum.nextInt(15)];
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
```

For context, genNum is an imported Random... object? tool thing

In my mind, this reads:

```
For all eternity:

If word == lastWord, get another random word from the word list until it isn't.

Print out word

Update lastWord

Get a new random word

Wait and return.
```

However, in the console, I still get consecutive duplicates here and there. This, to me, for some reason, implies an issue in the second while loop. Am I misunderstanding the while loop syntax, or is something else all fuckish?

Comment: It's totally okay for a random source to return same number twice or more times in a row. It just becomes less likely the larger the number source. But with just 15 numbers, you'd see that every 15th iteration (overall statistically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you find a new word you set `word = lastWord`. You might want to do `lastWord = word` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In any programming language the flow of storing the data is right to left. So whenever you want to save any value to some variable that variable must be on left side of "=" sign & the value must be at the right side of "="

For example:
you have variable number & you want to set value 10 to that variable, you must write like

number = 10;

So the value 10 would get stored in variable number.